# How to avoid that Django adds url link to every html element that follows the link

Tags: django, django-urls

i would like to achieve something very basic in Django but can't find out what I am doing wrong. On my apps "index.html", I would like to add a button which redirects to another html template ("site.html") with other content. I added the following to "index.html" which is working:

```
<body>
<h2>foo</h2>
    {% block content %}
    <button><a href="{% url 'site' %}"/>Click</button>
    {% endblock %}
<p>bar</p>
</body>
```

Clicking on the button gets me to "site.html", however all html items which I add on "index.html", for example the paragraph "bar" would also get rendered as hyperlink.
I tried creating different Django blocks or making different html sections but that doesn't fix it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing anchor `</a>` tag after your element.

```
<body>
<h2>foo</h2>
    {% block content %}
    <button><a href="{% url 'site' %}">Click</a></button>
    {% endblock %}
<p>bar</p>
</body>
```

I will note that I'm not sure it's "correct" to have an anchor tag within a button. I think you're better off styling your anchor tag to appear as a button.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. I didn't see the forest for the trees anymore.